# Sitecore Social Connector 2.1 not working with Sitecore 7.2

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2, sitecore-social-connected

Hi I am getting this error when I am trying to install Social Connected 2.1 in sitecore 7.2

**Could not find configuration node: 
contentSearch/configuration/defaultIndexConfiguration/analyzer**

Could not find solution.

Can anyone help me out with this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

Sitecore does have a workaround in place for the known issues:

> Using Social Connected 2.1 with Sitecore CMS 7.2 Reference number:
>   408378
>
> Social Connected 2.1 isn’t compatible with Sitecore CMS 7.2.
>
> Workaround:
>
> Install Social Connected module on Sitecore 7.2 rev. 140228. 
>   Install Social Connected 2.1 rev. 140113 using the Installation Wizard. During
>   installation, you'll get the following error message: "Could not find
>   configuration node: content Search/configuration/defaultIndex
>   Configuration/analyzer". Close the message. Make required changes* to
>   configuration files. Open the Installation Wizard and install the
>   module package again. Use the Skip option for items and files
>   conflicts. Fix Social Connected module that is already installed on
>   Sitecore 7.2 rev. 140228 Make required changes* to configuration
>   files.
>   * Required changes to the Sitecore.Social.config file:
>
> Change the analyzer tag from

```
<analyzer ref="contentSearch/configuration/defaultIndexConfiguration/analyzer" />
```

> to the following...

```
<analyzer ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration/analyzer" />
```

> Add the "true" tag to the
>   "socialSearch/configuration" section.

[*** You can find the official Sitecore workaround / KB article here ***](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/715286)

So you can use Social Connected 2.1 with this fix.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this!  Just a note that Sitecore moved the workaround to their Knowledge Base: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/715286

Answer (score 3):

I don't have any good news for you. **Social Connected** module doesn't have any version which is compatible with **Sitecore 7.2** version.

Here is the full table of the modules compatibility: http://sdn.sitecore.net/products/sitecore%20v5/sitecore%20cms%206/installation/modules%20compatibility.aspx.

The answer I've got from **Sitecore Support** is

> There is currently no supported by CMS 7.2 Social Connected. Reasons are - many breaking changes.

---

**EDIT:**

According to the latest news, there are now versions of Social Connected supporting Sitecore up to 7.5:

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/541788

Comment: Thanks Maras.. i guess i have to wait till they release it for 7.2.